# Is this ring an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm starting to study Algebraic number theory and I'm having problems with the first examples of this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439845980). I'm trying to prove this is a quadratic domain, i.e., an integral domain:

[image]

I'm sorry I know this is a stupid question, but I'm a really beginner on this subject trying to study it on his own.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Every subring of the field of complex numbers is a domain.

Comment: Or of any field, for that matter!

Comment: I didn't understand can you give me more details? $n$ is not necessarily negative. Where did you use the assumptions $n\equiv 1(\mod {4})$ and $n\not\equiv 1(\mod{4})$?

Comment: I did not use the assumptions because they are irrelevant in proving that a subring of the field of complex  numbers is an integral domain.

Comment: If n is not negative, then your ring is contained in the field of real numbers which is also contained in the field of complex numbers!

Comment: I suspect your book uses a definition of «integral domain» which is different from the one used by the rest of the universe.

Comment: That book uses the same definition of integral domain as "the rest of the universe".

Comment: In that case, those eassumptions are completely irrelevant in showing that  a subring of $\mathbb C$ is an integral domain (although they are not irrelevant in showing the set $\mathbb Z[\omega_n]$ as described in that qeestion is a subring: but you did not ask for help on doing this...)